# not able to play next song on clicking a button

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, onclick

I am new to android development.I created an audio player app for playing songs from SD card,its working fine and song is being played but when I click next button, song doesn't change and same track keeps playing.Button is clickable but song doesn't change on clicking it.How do I fix it ? any kind of help is appreciated,thanks.

```
public class PlayListActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] mAudioPath;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private String[] mMusicList;
    int currentPosition = 0;
    private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<>();

    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver;
    byte[] art;
    ImageView album_art;
    TextView album;
    TextView artist;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_list);

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        mMusicList = getAudioList();

        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                try {
                    playSong(mAudioPath[arg2]);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private String[] getAudioList() {
        final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA}, null, null,
                "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

        int count = mCursor.getCount();

        String[] songs = new String[count];
        mAudioPath = new String[count];
        int i = 0;
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                songs[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                mAudioPath[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                i++;
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        mCursor.close();

        return songs;
    }


    private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalStateException, IOException {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_building_music_player);
        Log.d("ringtone", "playSong :: " + path);

        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
//mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        acv(path);
        abc();
        cde();
    }

    public void acv(String path) {
        getInit();

        metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriver.setDataSource(path);
        try {
            art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
            album_art.setImageBitmap(songImage);
            album.setText(metaRetriver
                    .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
            artist.setText(metaRetriver
                    .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            album_art.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            album.setText("Unknown Album");
            artist.setText("Unknown Artist");
        }

    }

    public void getInit() {
        album_art = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coverart1);
        album = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Album);
        artist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
    }


    public void abc() {
        ImageButton btnPlay1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay1);
        btnPlay1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        btnPlay1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            mMediaPlayer.pause();
                        } else {
                            mMediaPlayer.start();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }




 public void cde() {
    ImageButton btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);  //this is the button for playing next song.
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try {
                        currentPosition=currentPosition+1;
                    playSong(path + songs.get(currentPosition));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
 public void next() {
        ImageButton btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        temp = temp + 1;
                        try {
                            playSong(mAudioPath[temp]);
                        } catch (Exception er) {
                            er.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Dont forget to declare `next()` method in `playsong()`